# save specific files with MATLAB commands

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to save models in oldest MATLAB versions as below 
I look for each folder and subfolder to find any .mdl or .slx to save it as 2007b version

The problem I have is :

1. it works if I just look for one extension whereas I'm wondering
   to do that on each .mdl and.slx .
2. the save_system takes too much
   time

Do you know how could I get all .mdl and .slx  and is there an optimized way to save ?

Thanks

```
rootPath = fullfile('M:\script\ytop','tables');
files = dir(rootPath );

for ii = 3:numel(files)

x = fullfile(rootPath ,files(ii).name);
cd(x);
mdl = { dir('*.mdl'),dir('*.slx')};  % here it works if only I set dir('*.mdl')
for jj = 1:numel(mdl)
    load_system(mdl(jj).name);
    save_system(mdl(jj).name,mdl(jj).name, 'SaveAsVersion','R2007b');
end   

end
```

Comment: 'R2017b'? Try it with 'R2007b'

Comment: oh sorry, :) it's just a mistake (of course I used 2007b)

Comment: I do not know whether or not there is a better function. I am a bit doubtful though since MATLAB actually have written a function supposed to do exactly this in a good way. However, I have had similar problems (but for .mat files). The problem was then that the network connection was terribly slow. Are the files big? Are there many files? Have you tried to transfer files between the machine where you have matlab and the `M` drive? If you did this (without loading or saving files), you could see how fast the connection is. Try this with the same file(s) and compare if this time is proportional.

Comment: @patrick, i also a second problème , How to say : i want to load and save all .mdl and .slx ?

Answer (score 1):

```
%here you used {} which created a cell array of two structs. cat creates a single struct which.
mdl=cat(1,dir('*.mdl'),dir('*.slx')); 
for jj = 1:numel(mdl)
    [~,sysname,~]=fileparts(mdl(jj).name);
    load_system(mdl(jj).name);
    %use only sysname without extension. R2007b is mdl only. You can't store files for R2007b in slx format
    save_system(sysname,sysname, 'SaveAsVersion','R2007b');
    %close system to free memory.
    close_system(sysname);
end
```

Applying only the required fixes your code has one odd behaviour. For mdls the file is replaced with the original one, for slx a mdl is created next to the original one. You may want to add a `delete(mdl(jj).name)` after loading.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this answer only contains the inner loop starting with `mdl=` Probably `dir` did not return anything because the `cd` is missing.