# Save Simulink models in old format

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to save Simulink models in old format , but the code below seems not working

I tried :

```
miF = fullfile('toi','mok','tables');
files = dir(miF);

for k = 3:numel(files)
x = fullfile(miF,files(k).name);
cd(x);
mdl = { dir('*.mdl'),dir('*.slx')};  % here it works if only I set dir('*.mdl')
for i = 1:numel(mdl)
    load_system(mdl(i).name);
    save_system(mdl(i).name,mdl(i).name, 'SaveAsVersion','R2012b');
end  
end
```

Comment: Another question with nearly identical code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632020/save-specific-files-with-matlab-commands

Comment: it works when x is a folder but if x is a .mdl it fail

Comment: Any idéal ?suggession ?